# Error paginating the videos in a playlist using Youtube Data API v3

Tags: youtube-data-api

I wrote some code to list all of the videos in a playlist using the Youtube Data API and it has been working for a year maybe. Starting yesterday I am getting an error response while using the nextPageToken.

Here is an example for the 4th page of a playlist:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?playlistId=UU65afEgL62PGFWXY7n6CUbA&maxResults=50&part=snippet&pageToken=CJYBEAA&key=<use your own key>
```

And here is the response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The request specifies an invalid page token.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request specifies an invalid page token.",
        "domain": "youtube.parameter",
        "reason": "invalidPageToken",
        "location": "pageToken",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Sometimes this happens on the 4th page, sometimes the 10th, it just seems to happen randomly. This also happens no matter which playlistId I am using. But when I use the Try it Out on the API docs for the page that failed, it always works:

[image]

Note that this code has worked consistently up until yesterday, maybe this is an error on the API side? I tried waiting 1 second in between page calls and that didn't make a difference.

Comment: I added a retry mechanism that will keep calling until it succeeds. A maximum of 5 retries was not enough, but 10 seems to be working. If the problem goes away it should work as it did before. Seems like Google is just trying to chew up my call quota. Would still like to figure out the cause of this though.

Comment: I'd suggest to report this directly to Google, through its [own issue tracker site](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Good idea @stvar. I created a bug there

Comment: It looks like this is not an issue with my code but is a bug with the Youtube API. Because of that I am going to close this question. Here is the issue that I opened for the bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196478069

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is it a known bug with the Youtube API